# Code rate in IEEE 802.11b (DSSS)

Tags: channelcoding

I would like to know what code rates for forward error correction the physical layer of IEEE 802.11b uses for the different supported data rates. So far I didn't find any source for that. Actually in the literature I found on 802.11b and DSSS code rates are never mentioned at all and hence I wonder if forward error correction is even applied.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

The 802.11 standard also doesn't mention FEC for the normal DSSS in 802.11b so I think it is not applied.

However for completeness there is an optional mode specified (DSSS/PBCC) which uses a binary convolutional coder with a code rate of 1/2.

Comment: Have you tried the standards themselves? http://standards.ieee.org/about/get/

Comment: @MBaz Thank you, that helped. The standard also doesn't mention FEC for the normal DSSS mode in 802.11b so I think it is not applied.
However there is an optional mode specified (DSSS/PBCC) which uses a binary convolutional coder with a code rate of 1/2.

Comment: Because CCK mode uses a spreading code instead of a FEC code (PBCC)